# Deserialize a JSON array partially into a HashMap with the help of jackson

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization

I have the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "a": 1,         
    "b": 2,                  
    "c": "one",
    "d": 3                     
  },
  {
    "a": 4,         
    "b": 5,                  
    "c": "two",
    "d": 6                     
  },
  {
    "a": 7,         
    "b": 8,                  
    "c": "three",
    "d": 9                     
  },
]
```

I want to cast this with the help of jackson into a `HashMap<String,Integer>` like this:

```
{
  "one": 2,
  "two": 5,
  "three": 8
}
```

I have tried a custom deserializer but I can't get it registered correctly and I don't really know if this is the correct way to do it. The next problem is that i don't have any nesting object as an actual basis for my JSON, means that I get it straight as a string like mentioned above, so I can't use any annotation like this:

`@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)`.

So at the end I need to register the Deserializer in the ObjectMapper itself, but this won't work either with the help of a configuration like this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
simpleModule.addDeserializer(new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Integer>>(){}, new CustomDeserializer());
```

Am I missing something here? I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: So you are trying to add each object's `c` value as key and `b` value as value into map?

Comment: @navnath That is right.

Comment: So basically, this is not just deserializing.  It is deserializing AND transforming.  And you are trying to do the two things in one step.  My advice would be try doing it as two steps.  1) deserialize to a list of custom objects (or a list of maps).  2) transform to the hashmap that you want.

Comment: @MartinNöbel Why not just deserialize as it is then loop through and create a map?

Comment: You should be able to implement the (say) `List<Map<String, String>>` -> `Map<String, String>` transformation using a `Stream`; i.e. without an explicit loop.

Comment: @navnath Ye I thought that there is a way doing it in one step with a custom deserialization. The normal deserialization into an array and the convertion into a map shouldn't be a problem. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @MartinNöbel can you share your `CustomDeserializer.class`

Comment: @navnath i don't really implemented the CustomDeserializer because I can't get it registered anyway. And there are enough posts about such a deserialization, so i would look for something like this if I could get it registered in any way.

Comment: @MartinNöbel Well you can check out my answer, I have tested it.

Comment: @StephenC I added an answer where the convertion is done in two steps with the help of streams. Nevertheless my goal was a high performance so the answer from navnath is the accepted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have missed with adding `module.addDeserializer`

HashMapValueDeserializer.class

```
public class HashMapValueDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<HashMap<String, String>> {
    @Override
    public HashMap<String, String> deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        HashMap<String, String> ret = new HashMap<String, String>();

        ObjectCodec codec = parser.getCodec();
        TreeNode node = codec.readTree(parser);

        for (JsonNode n : (ArrayNode)node){
            JsonNode c = n.get("c");
            JsonNode b = n.get("b");
            ret.put(c.asText(), b.asText());
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Test.class

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, MalformedURLException, JsonProcessingException {
    String jsonArray = "[{ \"a\" : \"1\", \"b\" : \"2\", \"c\" : \"one\", \"d\" : \"3\" }, { \"a\" : \"4\", \"b\" : \"5\", \"c\" : \"two\", \"d\" : \"6\" }, { \"a\" : \"7\", \"b\" : \"8\", \"c\" : \"three\", \"d\" : \"9\" }]";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    SimpleModule module =
        new SimpleModule("HashMapValueDeserializer", new Version(1, 0, 0, null, null, null));
    module.addDeserializer(HashMap.class, new HashMapValueDeserializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);

    HashMap<String, Integer> result = mapper.readValue(jsonArray, HashMap.class);
    System.out.println(result);
  }

}
```

Output :

```
{one=2, two=5, three=8}
```

Comment: Great this is working. I didn't know that the registration of an unparameterized HashMap is a possible way doing this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway if someone want to do it without the help of a custom deserializer, it can be done in two steps: converting the JSON array to a list of custom objects and then transforming this array to a map with the help of streams. Remember that the performance of this solution lies behind the accepted answer.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
//converting the json to a list
List<CustomObject> list = Arrays.asList(objectMapper.readValue(json, CustomObject[].class));
//converting the list to a map
Map<String,Integer> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(CustomObject::getString, CustomObject::getInteger));

//the custom object for the list (uses lombok for getters and setters)
@Getter
@Setter
public class CustomObject{

    @JsonProperty(value = "c")
    private String string;

    @JsonProperty(value = "b")
    private Integer integer;

}
```

However all of this can be done in one line:

```
Map<String,Integer> map = Arrays.stream(objectMapper.readValue(json, CustomObject[].class)).collect(Collectors.toMap(CustomObject::getString, CustomObject::getInteger));
```